# How can I clean and prevent mold/mildew growth on exterior granite stairs?

Tags: granite

How do I safely remove (what I think is) mold and mildew (see picture below!) from exterior granite stairs and how best to prevent it from forming again in the future?

I know pressure washing could be an option but wondering if there are any alternatives. Also the run-off could get into the lawn so would like to use something that won't be bad for the soil if that's where it ends up.

If it helps I live in a temperate climate where it rains often in non-summer months.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Pressure washing or scrubbing with water is the safest for lawn/garden.  Extra sunlight and ventilation/air movement  to prevent, but probably the hardest to provide.  Gardening site will probably know of safe chemicals.   https://gardening.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Try using a [residual cleaner](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0019KSUG6).  This cleaner does not remove the mold or mildew immediately.  However it kills the organism and seeps into all the nooks and crannies and stays active to keep killing off the spores.

My condo has used it on our tile roofs and they stayed clean for about 5 years.

Mix it with water in a pump sprayer and apply.